# How to access std::shared_ptr methods

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

everything is in the title.
Im new in C++ and im not sure that I undertand shared_ptr properly...

I've this method:

```
const std::set<Something::Ptr, b> & getSome() const;
```

that I use to get a set of somethings :

```
auto s = u->second.getSome();
```

After that i want to iterate on it with :

```
for(auto i = s.begin();i != s; s.end();i++)

//(so i=  std::shared_ptr<Something> referring to the first element in s )
```

My question is how can i access i methods?

I tried to understand what I was working with by debugging and cout some things :

```
auto whatIsThat1 = *i;
cout << "hello" << whatIsThat1; //>> hello0x13fd500

auto whatIsThat2 = i->get();
cout << "hello" << whatIsThat2; >> hello0x21c2500
```

Comment: I guess Arret::Ptr is a shared_ptr ?

Comment: "how can i access arretCourant methods" - dereference the shared_ptr, just like you would a raw pointer, and call the function... I fail to see the problem. In most use cases a `shared_ptr` behaves just like a raw pointer.

Comment: We can't tell when everything just says "something". Provide a [mcve]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused because `arretCourant` is *not* a `std::shared_ptr`. It is a `std::set` iterator referring to an element of the `std::set`, which *is* a `std::shared_ptr`.

So in order to call a method on the object that the `std::shared_ptr` points to, you need to first dereference the iterator to get a reference to the `std::shared_ptr` and then dereference again to get a reference to the object that the `std::shared_ptr` is pointing to. So to call a method on that object use:

```
(*arretCourant)->methodName()
```

`std::shared_ptr` overloads the `->` operator to make it call the method on the object pointed to, rather than the `std::shared_ptr` itself. It also overloads the indirection operator `*` to return a reference to the object it is pointing to, so

```
(**arretCourant).methodName()
```

also works.

If you use `arretCourant->methodName()` you are dereferencing the iterator, but not the `std::shared_ptr`, so you are calling `methodName()` on the `std::shared_ptr` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can dereference a [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) just like a raw pointer e.g.:

```
struct A{
   void method() {}
};
shared_ptr<A> a = make_shared<A>();
a->method();
```

you should not dereference if you needed a method of `std::shared_ptr` e.g.:

```
auto refCount = a.use_count();
```

Comment: @GuillaumeCharron please add your class to the question

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `Arret::Ptr`, you have an `std::set<Arret::Ptr, compArret>::const_iterator`. You will need to dereference it to get at the pointer (and dereference that to get at the underlying `Arret`)

You do get `Arret::Ptr`s if you use a ranged-for, e.g.

```
for (auto ptr : arrets)
{
    ptr->method();
}
```